# django can't find my choiceField on fields

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

I have my class:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Donator

class DonatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
      BLOOD_CHOICES = ( ('A-','A-'),      ('A+','A+'),      ('B-','B-'),      ('B+','B+'),      ('AB-','AB-'),    ('AB+','AB+'),    ('O-','O-'),      ('O+','O+'), ('TODOS','TODOS') )
      SITUATION_CHOICES = ( ('Sem Problemas','Sem Problemas'), ('Problemas Momentâneos','Problemas Momentâneos'), ('Problemas Graves', 'Problemas Graves') )

      class Meta:
            model = Donator
            fields = ('name', 'age', 'email','phone', forms.ChoiceField(choices = SITUATION_CHOICES, required=True, label = "Situacao do Doador"), 'bloodType', 'observation')
```

I receive:

> NameError: name 'SITUATION_CHOICES' is not defined

How could I correctly mention my fieldCHoices to appear a dropdown on the Form?

Also, It's already set on the  `model`. No way to get it from the model itself?

```
class Donator(models.Model):
      class Meta:
            ordering = ('name',)

      BLOOD_CHOICES = (
            ('A-','A-'),      ('A+','A+'),      ('B-','B-'),      ('B+','B+'),      ('AB-','AB-'),    ('AB+','AB+'),    ('O-','O-'),      ('O+','O+'), ('TODOS','TODOS')
      )
```

Comment: If it's on a field in the model, you don't need to do anything to use it in the form. You especially don't need to put that inside the `fields` tuple; that doesn't make any sense at all. Just remove it from there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman And How am I going to use it on the view when I call the form? Already tried to remove it and just place the field names inside `field[]`. But only the field name is displayed, not the dropDown

Answer (score 0):

You use your meta fields in a wrong way . your choices must be outside the model class.

```
BLOOD_CHOICES = (
            ('A-','A-'),      ('A+','A+'),      ('B-','B-'),      ('B+','B+'),      ('AB-','AB-'),    ('AB+','AB+'),    ('O-','O-'),      ('O+','O+'), ('TODOS','TODOS')
      )
class Donator(models.Model):
      blood_type = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
      class Meta:
            ordering = ('name',)
```

this way it should work

```
BLOOD_CHOICES = ( ('A-','A-'),      ('A+','A+'),      ('B-','B-'),      ('B+','B+'),      ('AB-','AB-'),    ('AB+','AB+'),    ('O-','O-'),      ('O+','O+'), ('TODOS','TODOS') )
SITUATION_CHOICES = ( ('Sem Problemas','Sem Problemas'), ('Problemas Momentâneos','Problemas Momentâneos'), ('Problemas Graves', 'Problemas Graves') )
class DonatorForm(forms.ModelForm):

          choiceFieldName = forms.ChoiceField(choices = SITUATION_CHOICES, required=True, label = "Situacao do Doador"), 'bloodType', 'observation')
          class Meta:
                model = Donator
                fields = ('name', 'age', 'email','phone','choiceFieldName' )
```